# Only some static files not displaying on Django / Apache stack

Tags: css, django, django-staticfiles

Trying to figure out how in the world all my images are loading fine with the exception of a few on one of my templates.  Keep in mind, all of this works perfectly in dev mode, but when I moved this to an Apache server, this is what happened.

Here is my site that you can see for yourself:

http://13.56.18.7/

my file structure:

[image]

If you look on the Homepage (/ directory) it is missing the main image, and 2 other images directly below that.  Also many of the styles are missing.  But, all images below this are showing up just fine.

Here is the HTML in question:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block contentHome %}

<style>
  .parallax {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("{% static 'images/FrontMain-2.png' %}");

    /* Set a specific height */
    height: 300px;

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */


    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
</style>

<!-- Container element -->
<div class="parallax" style="position: relative;">
  <div alt="buttonsDiv" style="right: 35px; bottom: 55px; position: absolute;">
    <a href="tel:+1-714-605-2950"><button style="margin-right: 20px;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i>&nbsp; 714-605-2950</button></a>
    <a href="{% url 'services_page' %}"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-wpforms fa-lg"></i>&nbsp; Contact Form</button></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

URLS.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from app_main.views import (home_page, services_page, history_page, offers_page, contact_page)
from django.conf.urls import url


urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_page),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('services/', services_page),
    url(r'^services/', services_page, name='services_page'),
    url(r'^history/', history_page, name='history_page'),
    url(r'^offers/', offers_page, name='offers_page'),
    url(r'^contact/', contact_page, name='contact_page'),
]
```

settings.py:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/
STATIC_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
     STATIC_DIR,
     STATIC_DIR+"/css",
     STATIC_DIR+"/images",
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

Here is my apache config:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess www-data processes=2 threads=12 python-path=/build/DoneRitePlumbing
WSGIProcessGroup www-data
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGILazyInitialization On
WSGIScriptAlias / /build/DoneRitePlumbing/DoneRitePlumbing/wsgi.py

<Directory /build/DoneRitePlumbing/DoneRitePlumbing>
    Require all granted
</Directory>


Alias /media/ /build/DoneRitePlumbing/media/
Alias /static/ /build/DoneRitePlumbing/static/

<Directory /build/DoneRitePlumbing/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /build/DoneRitePlumbing/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /build/DoneRitePlumbing/wsgi.py

<Directory /build/DoneRitePlumbing/DoneRitePlumbing>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

This same exact html exists on the "services" page and it renders just fine:

http://13.56.18.7/services/

if you look at chrome dev tools, you can see it's loading the services image fine:

[image]

but not the home page:

[image]

Must be something really dumb I am missing, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Can you put the apache configuration? You collected the static files etc?

Comment: I just added my apache config.  And yes, I collected the static files, not sure if I did it right, but I used the collectstatic command

Comment: in your urls.py you added `+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` ?

Comment: show us as well `STATIC_URL`, `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Comment: added settings.py and url.py

Comment: Where would I put that in url.py?  Where exactly would it go?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my configuration that works on apache

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
 ...your routes
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**apache** #I'm using windows not linux

```
<IfModule wsgi_module>
  WSGIPythonPath C:\project\src
  WSGIPythonHome C:\project\env

  Alias /media C:\project\src\media

  Alias /static C:\project\src\static

  <Directory C:\project\src\static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory C:\project\src\media>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  WSGIScriptAlias / C:\project\src\settings\wsgi.py

  <Directory C:\project\src>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>
```

Comment: You changed the path on apache configuration?

Comment: Yes, but I am wondering if I changed it correctly.

WSGIScriptAlias / /build/DoneRitePlumbing/DoneRitePlumbing/wsgi.py

<Directory /build/DoneRitePlumbing/DoneRitePlumbing>
    Require all granted
</Directory>